# Returning a Json-field from SQL to ASP.NET Core API

Tags: json, sql-server, asp.net-core, serialization

I'm building a relatively simple Get-method in an ASP.NET Core (3+) application. (Currently 3.1 - to be migrated to 5)

The object I need to return looks like this:

```
public class Data 
{
    public int ID { get;set;}
    public string Name { get;set;}
    public string Settings { get; set;}
}
```

And the Get-method is simply this:

```
public IActionResult<Data> GetData() 
{
    var data = _dbContext.GetData<Data>();
    return Ok(data);
}
```

This works perfectly - except for one thing.

In SQL - the settings column (varchar(8000)), contains JSON data. In some cases, a setting can be something simple like : { "threshold": 8754 } and sometimes it can be a large complex object with many fields, but it is always valid Json.

On the ASP side, it does exactly what you would expect. It turns a serialized Json object that contains an INT and 2 x strings.

I would like for it to return an INT, ONE String and One Json Object.

Is there any way that I can tell the serializer that the Settings-property contains Json?

In a perfect world, I would love something like this:

```
public class Data 
{
    public int ID { get;set;}
    public string Name { get;set;}
    
    [SerializeContentAsJson]
    public string Settings { get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way to do this or is there some other fairly elegant solution to this problem?

Btw. I fully realize that the caller can specify the content types that he/she will accept. In this case, the API is purely for use inside my team and we will always want JSON, so I can compromise on this being a relatively custom solution that might not work if you wanted text/html or some other content type.

Comment: JSON strings are strings, not objects. If you want to return objects from a JSON string you'll have to deserialize them. If you don't know the type of content in advance, you could use `dynamic`

Comment: If you were writing raw SQL you could use `JSON_VALUE`